# Why will my Ajax code not run?

Tags: ajax

I am trying to build a page that will display the next item in a PHP array when the user clicks on a button.  I'm a complete newbie on Ajax, and I am using the "Head First Ajax" book as a guide.  My code (below) doesn't work and I don't understand why.  Quite frankly, I am not even sure how to debug Ajax...

The code is in a file called `Index.php`.  I am using WampServer.

The page loads properly.  Here is the code:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
  var id=null;
  function getRequest(){
    try {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (MS){
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (MoreMS){
        try {
          request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (failure){
          request = null;
        }
      }
    }
    return request;
  }

  function showNext(itemId){
    request=getRequest();
    if(request==null){
      alert("Request object is null");
      return;
    }
    var url="index.php?itemId="+escape(itemId);
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(request.readyState==4){
        alert("Request.readyState is 4");
        if(request.status==200){
          alert("Request.status is 200");
          document.getElementById('article').value=request.responseText;
        }else{
          alert("Request.status not 200");
          return;
        }
      }else{
        alert("Request.readystate not 4");
        return;
      }
    }
    request.send(null);
  }

  function getItemId(){
    if(id==null){
      id=0;
    }else{
      id=id+1;
    }
    return id;
  }

  function doIt(){
    itemId=getItemId();
    showNext(itemId);
  }
</script></head>
<body><p>
  <textarea id='article'>
  </textarea>
</p>  
<p>
  <button type="button" id='showNext1' onclick="doIt()" >Show next</button>
</p></body></html>

<?php
  $array=array(10,21,32,43,54,65,76);
  if(!isset($_GET['itemId'])){
  }else{
    echo $array[$_GET['itemId']];
  }
  var_dump("GET :",$_GET);
?>
```

When I click the button, here is what happens:

I get **twice** the `Request.readystate not 4` alert, then once `Request.readyState is 4`, then once `Request.status is 200`, then the `textarea` gets populated, and then again **once** `Request.readystate not 4`.  After all that the `textarea` contains my entire code followed by this:

```
10<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'GET :'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'itemId' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
</pre>
```

Then if I click again I get the same alerts and output except that at the end I get `21<pre class='xdebug-var-dump'....`.  Next click produce the same except with `32<pre class....` at the end, etc.

Comment: Consider putting some error handling in your `showItem` function

Comment: Done, I don't get any error on the `readystate` or `status`.  I'll modify my question.

Comment: Your ajax calls are so old styled. Try using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm still learning Ajax.  I don't want to add a layer of abstraction until I have a good hang of it.  I'm sure I'll get to jQuery eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the function for `onreadystatechange` event inline. Also, the textarea's value is accessed using `value`, not `innerHtml`. The modified `showNext()` would be:

```
function showNext(itemId){
    request=getRequest();
    if(request==null){
        return;
    }
    var url="index.php?itemId="+escape(itemId);
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.onreadystatechange= function(){
        if(request.readyState==4){
            if(request.status==200){
            document.getElementById('article').value=request.responseText;
            }
        }   
    }
    request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Why is it better to define the function inline?

Comment: because you need to access `request` object.

Comment: I see.  The scope of `request` is local - is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes. if you want to use external function, you can call it with `responseText` as parameter.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I'll modify my initial question to reflect the changes you recommended.

Comment: I found a missing `;`, and I modified the code accordingly.  Still, the output doesn't make sense.  I modified the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: jd42 - I suspect this will work, but I don't understand why.  I need to ask a separate question.

Comment: JDelage - because it will throw the html part and also parse the php code